# Convert multiple columns with dynamic data to one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table with the following structure:

| ID_Employee | 1_1 Question | 1_2 Question | 2_1 Question | 2_2 Question | 3_1 Question | 3_2 Question |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | answer1_1 | answer1_2 | answer2_1 | answer2_2 | answer3_1 | answer3_2 |
| Second | answer1_1 | answer1_2 | answer2_1 | answer2_2 | answer3_1 | answer3_2 |

Mention that the answers are variable, that is, they do not have static data
but I need to sort this table under the following structure:

| ID_Employee | Question1 | Question2 | Question3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | answer1_1 | answer2_1 | answer3_1 |
| First | answer1_2 | answer2_2 | answer3_2 |
| Second | answer1_1 | answer2_1 | answer3_1 |
| Second | answer1_2 | answer2_2 | answer3_2 |

I will appreciate if someone can guide me how I could carry out this process. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more columns to be unpivoted togther (say `Question1,Question2` etc), it's easier to use `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot instead of `UNPIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT
    t.ID_Employee,
    v.Question1,
    v.Question2,
    v.Question3
FROM yourtable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    ([1_1 Question], [2_1 Question], [3_1 Question]),
    ([1_2 Question], [2_2 Question], [3_2 Question])
) v(Question1, Question2, Question3)
```

Comment: could this work? knowing that my answers are variable? and these are data, not columns

Comment: Sorry you're right missed that. So what are your extra columns that you want ot unpivot?

Comment: thanks, the structure I have in my table is similar to the one here:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2e20000ba6c2d14e0e368ae5d95fe799, so, I need to group my data by main questions (Question 1, Question 2, Question 3, ...) with their respective data in rows, not columns anymore

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and show me expected output, not fully clear what you want. What do the two `1`s in `Question1_1` represent?

Comment: ok, I already edited it ... I hope you understand

Comment: OK got it for you now

Answer (score 0):

you need to `unpivot` your data:

```
SELECT ID_Employee , questions
FROM
(SELECT * FROM yourtable) pv
UNPIVOT
(questions FOR EmployeeIds IN ( Question1,Question2,Question3,Question4) )  unpvt;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ca4b0393bfde7a2b8a5bf99d9d74d5a)

Comment: Great, works perfect ... thank you very much ...
a query, if I wanted to add another unpivot based on other columns in the same table, how could I do it?

Comment: you have to gibe me more information , show the desired output but unpivot/pivot only works for one set of columns to be pivot/unpivot , so probably you need to do it in seperate query

Comment: The desired table is similar to the one shown in the unpivot, only that I want to add more columns, for example question2, question3 ... questionN, starting from the same initial structure with more question fields added in a row..I hope I have explained myself

Comment: | ID_Employee | Question     | Question2    |.....
| ----------- | ------------ | ------------ |
| First       | answer1      | answer1      |
| First       | answer2      | answer2      |
| First       | answer3      | answer3      |
| First       | answer4      | answer4      |
| Second      | answer1      | answer1      |
| Second      | answer2      | answer2      |
| Second      | answer3      | answer3      |
| Second      | answer4      | answer4      |

Comment: yeah , you can't do that , you need to use cross apply as the other answer mentioned